# UITableViewController cell remains highlighted when segueing back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` and when a cell is selected, my app segues to a new view controller.  When I press the back button in my navigation controller to go back to the previous tableview controller, the cell that I had selected remains highlighted.  I checked `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` in `viewWillAppeaer` and it is true.  Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the segue from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if so try something like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("Your Segue", sender: indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

You could also place `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath` the in the `prepareForSegue` method which is what I tend to do

Comment: Sweet!  Any idea why `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` isn't doing the job.

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/